How to get separate results for combined DBActions in Slick
I need help on this situation.
I have to insert multiple records in table A and a single record in table B. I need all of them in a single transaction but also need to get separate results for each DBAction
    val tableAInserts:Seq[ProfileAction] = Seq(insertAction1TableA, insertAction2TableA, insertAction3TableA, ...)
    val tableBInsert:ProfileAction = singleInsertProfileActionTableB

    val allActions = Seq(tableAInserts) ++ tableBInsert
    db.run(DBIO.sequence(allActions).transactionally)

So I need to know how many inserts were done for tableA and how many for tableB separately
Is this possible?
Thanks for any guidance.

You can try to use for-comprehension with DBIO actions:
val tableA = TableQuery[TableA]
val tableB = TableQuery[TableB]

val tableAInserts: DBIO[Option[Int]] = tableA ++= Seq(...)
val tableAInserts1: DBIO[Option[Int]] = tableA ++= Seq(...)
//...
val tableBInsert: DBIO[Int] = tableB += (...)

val allActions: DBIO[(Option[Int], Option[Int], Int)] = (for {
  optN  <- tableAInserts
  optN1 <- tableAInserts1
  // ...
  m     <- tableBInsert
} yield (optN, optN1, m)).transactionally

val fut: Future[(Option[Int], Option[Int], Int)] = db.run(allActions)

or
val allActions: DBIO[Seq[Option[Int]]] = (for {
  optNs <- DBIO.sequence(Seq(tableAInserts, tableAInserts1))
  m     <- tableBInsert
} yield optNs :+ Some(m)).transactionally

val fut: Future[Seq[Option[Int]]] = db.run(allActions)

